# Which config allows to activate css style inside extjs tabpanel

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, tabpanel

I have tab panel inside the panel class. How I can to use CSS for tab panel items (title cls) and items of tab panel items (for example cls for button inside form inside tab panel). Cls config doesn't work. So what the problem?
same CSS work for other panels, but not for this case

```
Ext.define('Foresto.view.forms.Cutarea', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: 'Forestcut',
    layout:'fit',
    autoHeight: true,
    margin: 5,

    height: 600,
    header: {
        cls: 'header-cls',

    },
    scrollable: true,

    xtype: 'foresto-cutarea',

    url: 'save-form.php',

    defaults: {
        xtype: 'selectfield',
        labelWrap: true,
        afterLabelTextTpl: [
            '<span style="color:red;font-weight:normal" data-qtip="Required">*</span>'
        ]
    },

    items: [{
        xtype:'tabpanel',
        fullscreen: true,
        userCls: 'header-cls',
        shadow:true,
        items:[{
            xtype:'panel',
            title:'Data1',
            cls: 'header-cls',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'N',
                name: 'name'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'N1',
                name: 'allotment'
            },{
                xtype:'button',
                text:'save',
                margin: 10,
                ui:'confirm'
            }]
        },{
            xtype:'panel',
            title:'Charac',
            cls: 'header-cls',
            items:[{
                xtype:'selectfield',
                label:'n1'
            },{
                xtype:'button',
                text:'save',
                margin: 10,
                ui:'confirm'
            }]
        }

        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Provide your css code as well ?

Comment: .header-cls{
    background-color: #447433;
}

Comment: adding defaults config object above items means you want each item within items to be of type you have declared inside of defaults, in this case you xtype: 'selectfield' declared in defaults but than have xtype tabpanel inside of items first element, what exactly are you trying to achieve?